# What kind of handlebar is this? Why is it not symmetric?

Tags: handlebars, adaptive

I recently saw a video in some social network where a person is replacing a handlebar on an MTB.

Both the old and new bars have one side bent upwards and one side bent downwards.

What is the purpose of such handlebar and how is it called?

I cannot rule out that the whole thing is a joke, the bar seems "factory made", i.e. it does not look like a botched/diy work. However, I can think of ways of making a "prop" to look like the thing in the video. The video appeared to be "serious". It was not a "tutorial" but rather a quick "I'm telling you I replaced my h.b.".

At first, I thought that it might be for users that have one arm longer than the other, but the person in the video does not seem to have such condition and there is no speech/voice over nor captions or any text, except in the very first few seconds, a voice states that the new one is an upgrade because it is reinforced.

Here is an screenshot I took while the video was paused.

[image]

Comment: never seen one of those in all my days.

Comment: Maybe it's for a circuit track with all right turns?

Comment: The sharp angles to make the riser bar are needless weak points, likely not a real handle bar.

Comment: My money is "for the lulz" or some one-off bizzare purpose

Comment: Can you include a link to "*a video in some social network*" ?

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't have a link to the video. I lost it while saving the picture. This app, when you close and return to it, it starts in "home" again. Only with luck I'd stumble upon it again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As agreed with Criggie in chat i'm writing my own answer that builds upon his.

This is an asymmetric handlebar designed to help with a mobility issue.
The rider in question ([facebook.com/josemarialpz82](https://facebook.com/josemarialpz82)) had an elbow fracture that didn't heal well and can no longer fully extend his right arm.

Criggie identified the following video of the bars being fitted: https://www.tiktok.com/@josemaria_lpz/video/7148116755397774598?is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7148116755397774598&lang=en

The rider has also converted road and triathlon bikes with asymmetric bars.  Here is a video of a gravel bike conversion:

*Note: The video is in Spanish*